# DaoException: Entity is detached from DAO context

Tags: greendao

I have two entities, `User` and `Store`. `User` has many `Stores` (1:M) relation. I've inserted some stores list into the store table by following code.

```
public void saveStoresToDatabase(Context context, ArrayList<Store> storeList) {

    DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context, "notes-db", null);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);

    DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    StoreDao storeDao = daoSession.getStoreDao();

    ArrayList <Store> list = SharedData.getInstance().getUser().getStoreList();

    for(int i = 0; i < storeList.size(); i++) {
        storeList.get(i).setUserIdForStore(SharedData.getInstance().getUser().getId());
    }
    storeDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(storeList);
    list.addAll(storeList);
    user.resetStoreList();

}
```

I am getting "entity is detached from DAO context" exception whenever I try call  `user.getStoreList()`. The exception occurs at following code sniped as the `daoSession` is `null`.

```
public ArrayList<Store> getDMStoreListFromDatabase(Context context) {
    return SharedData.getInstance().getUser().getStoreList();
}
```

where `SharedData` is my singleton, having a user object:

```
private SharedData() {
    user = new User();
}
```

and I get the `sharedData` instance as follow:

```
public static synchronized SharedData getInstance() {
    if (sharedObject == null) {
        sharedObject = new SharedData();
    }
    return sharedObject;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code about where do you get the user-object and where do you call user.getStoreList(). Are you sure the storeList is inserted into your db correctly? Are you sure there is a StoreList for the selected user in the db?

Comment: i've edited my question by putting some code,  yes i am sure that the storeList is inserted, although i am inserting in transaction but i've also checked it by inserting the list elements one by one. There is only one user so yes i am sure that the storeList for the selected user is in the db as it was successfully inserted. Is there any way to  view the database tables ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Objects representing database entries (like `User`) are only attached to a Database-session if they have been fetched from the database or inserted to the database before.

It looks like you don't load your user-object using greendao, but instead just create it with `new`.

You also seem not to store this user-object using the dao. Thus the user-object is not attached to the session.

On top of that you are also just setting the userid in each store. If you haven't inserted the user-object somewhere else this may also cause an error since the foreignkey-constraint may be broken (depending on how greendao handles this internally).

Try to add the user-object to the stores with `setUser()` instead of `setUserIdForStore()`.

If this doesn't work try to store or load the user-object first using a `UserDao`.

Comment: The suggestion "store/load the user-object first using a UserDao" worked. About setting the "setUserIdForStore()",i was doing so to set the id for each store i am going to insert in db, server might return list of same stores that are already inserted to database, so i am replacing the userIdForStore key for the downloaded storesList with the logged in userId to make insertOrReplace successful, however, duplicate records are being inserted each time the storeList is fetched and inserted to db. Can you pin point the possible cause?

Comment: I don't understand your needs exactly. A user has many stores and a store belongs to one user, right? If you want to add a store to a specific user, try to set the user using the whole user-object not just the id. You are using a ORM-Framework, so try not to mess around with id, but use the objects. Otherwise strange behaviours may occur.